Tarski's Lemma in book Models and Ultraproducts
I'm currently reading the book Models and Ultraproducts by Bell & Slomson. In section $4$ of chapter $1$, they present a result they refer to as Tarski's lemma.
(I have rephrased the statement so that it's more readable)
Theorem 4.10. Let $\{A_{n}\}_{n \in \omega}$ be a countable collection of subsets of a Boolean algebra $B$ each having an infimum, and let $x \in B$ be such that $x \neq 0$. There exists an ultrafilter $U$ containing $x$ such that for all $n \in \omega$
$$ \pi \left( \bigwedge A_{n} \right) = \bigwedge  \pi \left( A_{n} \right), $$
where $\pi$ is the canonical homomorphism of $B$ onto $B/U \cong \textbf{2}$.
Here $\mathbf{2}$ denotes the two-element Boolean algebra, so since $U$ is an ultrafilter, the quotient $B/U$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{2}$.
This result is needed to prove the completeness of a predicate calculus in a subsequent chapter. To me, the previous result feels very ad-hoc and the proof a little bit hard to digest.

Does anyone know if this result goes by another name or its origins?

Is it possible to rephrase the previous result using some form of continuity?



I've seen this called the Rasiowa-Sikorski lemma.

This is what's called a Baire category argument. As shown in the text, it's possible to present the proof in a way that doesn't mention any topology. But I think the topological point of view is informative, so I'll describe it.
Recall that for any Boolean algebra $B$, there is a space $S(B)$, the Stone space of $B$, whose points are the ultrafilters on $B$. The topology on $S(B)$ is generated by basic open sets $O_b=\{U\in S(B)\mid b\in U\}$ for each $b\in B$. Since $O_{\lnot b} = S(B)\setminus O_b$, these basic open sets are actually clopen, and it's not hard to show that $S(B)$ is compact Hausdorff.
Now let $A\subseteq B$ be a subset of $B$ with infimum $a$. An ultrafilter $U$ preserves the meet $\bigwedge A=a$ if and only if either $a\in U$ or $\lnot b\in U$ for some $b\in A$. Letting $V_A$ be the set of all $U\in S(B)$ preserving this meet, $V_A=O_a\cup\bigcup_{b\in A} O_{\lnot b}$, so $V_A$ is open in $S(B)$. I claim that $V_A$ is dense. Let $O_c$ be a non-empty basic open set. If there is $b\in A$ such that $O_c\cap O_{\lnot b}$ is non-empty, we're done. So assume $O_c\cap O_{\lnot b} = \varnothing$ for all $b\in A$. Then $c\land \lnot b = \bot$, so $c\leq b$ for all $b\in B$. But then $c\leq a$, so $O_c\subseteq O_a$, and any $U\in O_c$ is in $V_A$.
Now let $(A_n)_{n\in \omega}$ be a countable family of subsets of $B$, such that $A_n$ has infimum $a_n$. We showed above that each $V_{A_n}$ is a dense open set. By the Baire category theorem, $\bigcap_{n\in \omega} V_{A_n}$ is dense. So for any $x\in B$ with $x\neq \bot$, $O_x\cap \bigcap_{n\in \omega} V_{A_n}$ is non-empty. Thus there is an ultrafilter $U$ with $x\in U$ which preserves all the meets $\bigwedge A_n = a_n$.

The topology in this proof can be replaced by the Rasiowa-Sikorski lemma. This brings us very close to the proof presented in Bell and Slomson, but I think factoring out the lemma makes the proof more intuitive. For Boolean algebras, the Rasiowa-Sikorski lemma can be phrased as follows:
Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra. A subset $D\subseteq B$ is dense if for any $x\in B$ with $x\neq \bot$, there is $d\leq x$ with $d\neq \bot$ and $d\in D$.
Lemma: Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra. Let $(D_n)_{n\in \omega}$ be a countable family of dense subsets of $B$. Then for all $x\in B$, $x\neq \bot$, there is an ultrafilter $U\subseteq B$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\cap D_n\neq \varnothing$ for all $n\in \omega$.
Proof: We build a descending sequence $(d_n)_{n\in \omega}$ with $d_n\neq \bot$ and $d_{n+1}\in D_n$ for all $n$. Let $d_0 = x$. Given $d_n$, by density of $D_n$, pick $d_{n+1} \leq d_n$ with $d_{n+1}\neq \bot$ and $d_{n+1}\in D_n$. Now $F = \{b\in B\mid \exists n\in \omega, d_n\leq x\}$ is a proper filter containing $x$ and meeting each $D_n$. If we extend $F$ to an ultrafilter $U$, $U$ has the same properties. $\square$
Now let's use the Rasiowa-Sikorski Lemma to prove the theorem. First we alter the topological density proof above to an order-theoretic density proof.
Let $A\subseteq B$ have infimum $a$. Let $D = \{x\in B\mid x\leq a\text{ or }\exists b\in A, x\leq \lnot b\}$. I claim that $D$ is dense in $B$. Let $x\in B$, $x\neq \bot$. If there is $b\in A$ such that $x\cap \lnot b\neq \bot$, then $y = x\cap \lnot b\in D$ and $y\leq x$, so we're done. Otherwise, for all $b\in A$, $x\cap \lnot b = \bot$, so $x\leq b$. Thus $x\leq a$, and $x\in D$ itself.
Now let $(A_n)_{n\in \omega}$ be a countable family of subsets of $B$, such that $A_n$ has infimum $a_n$, and let $x\in B$ with $x\neq \bot$. For each $n\in \omega$, let $D_n = \{x\in B\mid y\leq a_n\text{ or }\exists b\in A_n, y\leq \lnot b\}$. As shown above, each $D_n$ is dense. By the Rasiowa-Sikorski Lemma, there is an ultrafilter $U\subseteq B$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\cap D_n\neq \varnothing$ for all $n\in \omega$.
Then for each $n$, either there is $y\in U$ such that $y\leq a_n$, so $a_n\in U$, or there is $y\in U$ such that $y\leq \lnot b$ for some $b\in A$, so $\lnot b\in U$ for some $b\in A$. In either case, $U$ preserves the meet $\bigwedge A_n = a_n$.

Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.
